# Pandas to ODBC connection with to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to export a pandas DataFrame into an MS Access table through `pyodbc`.

```py
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=my_db.accdb;')

df.to_sql('test', conn, index=False)

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;':
('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'sqlite_master'.
Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly. (-1305) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

`sqlite_master`? Where does that come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.to_sql()` expects the second argument to be either a SQLAlchemy `Connectable` object or a DBAPI `Connection` object. If it is the latter then pandas *assumes* that it is a SQLite connection.

You need to use the [sqlalchemy-access](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access) dialect.

(Disclosure: I maintain that dialect.)

Comment: OK, thanks. It doesn't seem to be available as a conda package, and since I don't have VS Studio installed on my work PC to compile for a pip installation, that looks like a dead end.

Comment: If you already have pyodbc installed and if SQLAlchemy is available via conda then `pip install --no-deps sqlalchemy-access` might do the trick.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I didn't know that trick, thanks!